# Proxy Client: unable to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx ("Connection refused")

Tags: configuration, censorship, support

I am behind a firewall. I am not able to restricted sites using tor.
But the thing is I was able to use tor before some days. 
I am getting an error,

```
[notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
[notice] We now have enough directory information to build circuits.
[warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:38980 ("Connection refused")
[warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:47779 ("Connection refused")
[notice] Our directory information is no longer up-to-date enough to build circuits: We have no usable consensus.
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Under Tor Bridges Configuration, I had the transport type set to obfs3, probably because that used to be the recommended setting. When I changed it to obfs4, the current recommended setting, it worked again.

Answer (score 4):

Your log tells you, that you

> have no usable consensus.

So I guess, its not about the *restricted sites* you like to visit, its about your firewall, not letting you connect to the tor-default bridges behind 109.105.109.163. 
Restart your Tor-Client and read this information for a possible solution: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#BehindANAT